# How to tell quarkus to use java 17?

Tags: gradle, quarkus, java-17, switch-expression

I keep gettring build error saing that I'm using a preview feature (switch expressions):

```
Service.java:28: error: patterns in switch statements are a preview feature and are disabled by default.
      case CalssA sr -> sr.getMeterReadings();
           ^
  (use --enable-preview to enable patterns in switch statements)
```

I clearly said in build.gradle that I want to use Java 17. Switch expression were [released in Java 14](https://openjdk.org/projects/jdk/14/#:%7E:text=361%3A,Switch%20Expressions%20(Standard)).

Here are my `gradle.properties`, `settings.gradle`, and `build.gradle`:

```
quarkusPluginVersion=3.0.1.Final
quarkusPlatformArtifactId=quarkus-bom
quarkusPluginId=io.quarkus
quarkusPlatformGroupId=io.quarkus.platform
quarkusPlatformVersion=3.0.1.Final
```

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    plugins {
        id "${quarkusPluginId}" version "${quarkusPluginVersion}"
    }
}
rootProject.name='upc'
```

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.197'
    }
}


plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'io.quarkus'
    id 'org.flywaydb.flyway' version '9.8.1'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    def lombok_version = '1.18.26'
    def map_struct_version = '1.5.5.Final'

    implementation enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}")
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-qute'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-arc'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-flyway'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-validator'
    implementation 'io.quarkiverse.jdbc:quarkus-jdbc-sqlite:3.0.5'
    implementation 'io.quarkiverse.mybatis:quarkus-mybatis:2.0.0'
    implementation 'org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging'
    implementation "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:${map_struct_version}"
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-guava:2.14.2'


    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombok_version}"
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombok_version}"
    annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${map_struct_version}"

    testCompileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombok_version}"
    testAnnotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombok_version}"
    testAnnotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${map_struct_version}"

    testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5'
    testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured'
}

group 'org.acanthite'
version '0.1'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

test {
    systemProperty 'java.util.logging.manager', 'org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager'
}



compileJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    options.compilerArgs += [
            '-parameters',
            '-Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=cdi',
            '-Amapstruct.defaultInjectionStrategy=constructor'
    ]
}

compileTestJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    options.compilerArgs += [
            '-parameters',
            '-Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=cdi',
            '-Amapstruct.defaultInjectionStrategy=constructor'
    ]
}
```

Here are IDEA settings for project:
[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other place I need to specify Java version?

Comment: Please [edit] the post and remove the lorem ipsum. --- This does not seem like a quarkus issue, but more like a gradle issue. If we generate a bootstrap project from [`code.quarkus.io`](https://code.quarkus.io/?b=GRADLE), we find this part in the `build.gradle`: `java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}`. This is mssing from the config shown.

Comment: No, it's actually in my config. Just scroll a bit more to the bottom of the code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks I got what's wrong.

Gradle and quarkus are fine and work perfectly.

The problem is that I'm not using `switch expressions` but `switch pattern matching`, which look similar, but are a totally different thing. They are a preview feature in Java 17. Nevertheless, there is a compiler flag `--enable-preview` which somehow works for non-test builds, but fails when run tests. See this issue: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/10472